# Pass secrets from GitHub Actions to Docker image as env variable

Tags: docker, github-actions

How I can pass my secret from GitHub Actions to Docker image as env variable?

Dockerfile:

```
...
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=TOKEN \
    export TOKEN=$(cat /run/secrets/TOKEN) 

...
```

GitHub Actions workflow:

```yaml
...
        name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_LOGIN }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PWD }}
      -
        name: Build and push
        id: docker_build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          file: ./Dockerfile
          platforms: linux/amd64
          push: true
          tags: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_LOGIN}}/${{ secrets.DOCKER_NAME }}:latest
          secrets: |
            "TOKEN=${{ secrets.TOKEN_DEV }}"
```

Comment: my program needs the TOKEN env variable, but it is still empty

Comment: git actions log: 
```#14 [*** 3/5] RUN --mount=type=secret,id=TOKEN     export TOKEN=$(cat /run/secrets/TOKEN) &&     echo $TOKEN
#14 0.095 ***
```
TOKEN seems to be preserved. So why can't I get it from the program?