# The secrets are not being applied in docker/build-push-action

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions, buildx

I attempted to verify if the secrets were correctly applied based on [this link](https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/secrets/), but contrary to my expectations, it did not work.

Here is a question similar to mine:
[Pass secrets from git action to docker image as env variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69917498/pass-secrets-from-git-action-to-docker-image-as-env-variable)

- Workflow

  ```yaml
        - uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v3
        - uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3
        - uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
          with:
            context: apps/vc-screening-service
            platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm64
            push: true
            tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
            secrets: |
              "VC_MYSQL_USER=${{ secrets.VC_MYSQL_USER }}"
  ```
- Dockerfile

  ```
  # syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
  FROM alpine
  RUN --mount=type=secret,id=VC_MYSQL_USER \
    VC_MYSQL_USER=$(cat /run/secrets/VC_MYSQL_USER)
  ```
- GitHub Actions output

  [image]
- Docker run output:

  ```
  docker run -it 997245385850.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/dev/vc-screening-service:latest sh
  / # env
  HOSTNAME=6a893ca9c566
  SHLVL=1
  HOME=/root
  TERM=xterm
  PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
  PWD=/
  / #
  ```

The environment variable `VC_MYSQL_USER` is missing. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: can you remove quotes around VC_MYSQL_USER secret variable
VC_MYSQL_USER=${{ secrets.VC_MYSQL_USER }}

Comment: @DayanandaDR It's the same even after removal.

Comment: you need to add secret as env at a job level or at the workflow level
env:
  VC_MYSQL_USER: ${{ secrets.VC_MYSQL_USER }}

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Could you explain it in more detail?

Comment: @HwanE: According to docs (see [here](https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/secrets/) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#env)), your approach looks fine. Have you verified if `secrets.VC_MYSQL_USER` is configured correctly? You can `echo` it in the Dockerfile as well for verification i.e. `VC_MYSQL_USER=$(cat /run/secrets/VC_MYSQL_USER) echo "$VC_MYSQL_USER"`.

Comment: @Azeem Added a photo.

Comment: @HwanE: Everything from configuration to passing secrets to the action seems fine. Did you try that `echo` in Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

```
  - uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
    with:
      context: apps/vc-screening-service
      build-args: |
        "VC_MYSQL_USER=${{ secrets.VC_MYSQL_USER }}" 
      platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm64
      push: true
      tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
      secrets: |
        "VC_MYSQL_USER=${{ secrets.VC_MYSQL_USER }}"
```

You were not passing passing VC_MYSQL_USER  as a build argument, you need to add
ARG VC_MYSQL_USER  in your dockerfile as well

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM alpine
ARG VC_MYSQL_USER 
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=$VC_MYSQL_USER \
  VC_MYSQL_USER=$(cat /run/secrets/$VC_MYSQL_USER)
```